# How to fix internal sd mounting error?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, internal-storage

I have a T-Mobile Vibrant <strike>i9000</strike> SGH-T959 variant phone,

phone suddenly stops working error message:

```
movinand open fail

 E:Can't mount /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 (or
 /dev/block/mmcblk0) (No such file or
 directory) E:copy_dbdata_media:Can't
 mount SDCARD: copy default media
 content failed
```

Is there anything to fix this ?

I tried various odin roms, only one working: `Eugene_2E_JK2_Froyo.tar.md5`
phone booting up but, settings → sdcard and phone storage says: `unavailable`

Answer (score 2):

It does sound like your internal storage has been corrupted, but I don't know if I would try to format it via your PC. this is not actually an "SDCard", it is the internal storage on the device (which is a SGH-T959, not an I9000).

I would revert back to STOCK ROM using ODIN and return the phone under warranty. If you are already having issue with the internal storage, I would want a new device.

Now I guess you could try and format it via your pc (I dont know if you can even access it when its mounted via USB because I never mount it) but I, personally, would not, I would get a new device.

For reference, the i9000 is the international version of the Galaxy S phones. None of the US carriers sell the i9000. They sell different versions of the the Galaxy S phones. For example, the T-Mobile Vibrant is the SGH-T959, The Verzion Fascinate is SCH-i500, the AT&T Captivate is SGH-I897. While they are ALL Galaxy S phones, they are all also different devices. They have different hardware, like some have a front facing camera, led flash, 4 buttons, etc.

Comment: is there way to format internal sd? phone options unclickable. adb format possible ? and there is no way to send warranty, I'm in different country

Comment: I think you can format the sdcard in ODIN... been a while since I flashed with ODIN though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Check the "Re-Partition" option in ODIN.

Comment: already tryed, result same :(

Comment: It definitely sounds like there is something seriously wrong with your internal storage. I would see if there is any way you can send it in under warrenty

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue on my Droid 3 after I installed a Deoxded Stock ROM.  I was able to install Titanium Backup, but could never access my backup directory.

Ended up that I never disconnected my phone from my PC and while connected it would not allow bidirectional access (from PC and from phone).  Disconnected it from my PC and volia, my Internal SD Storage showed up.

Answer (score 1):

On my I9000 (galaxy S) this just means that something has changed the file-system within the phone like `ext2>ext4` and the current kernel doesn't support it..

Normally happens when flashing custom roms without checking the kernel requirements.... like I did :-(

The only way round it is to reflash using odin with a `512.pit` file and make sure you select re-partition..

Answer (score 0):

I think your internal SDCARD was corrupted, you can try connecting the device to the PC in external disk mode and try formatting the sd card from windows.

Comment: nope, not work. says: insert disk and try again